# Unable to create On-Off graph with DyGraphs?

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I have been using DyGraphs for a short time and have it displaying graphs well and seems to be working as expected with varying data from a temperature sensor.
Where I am having trouble is trying to create and on-off type graph where I detect a switch is on or off. I have tried to look at writing a custom plotter but quickly halt as can't find any reference to what commands etc I can use.

As a simple case, lets say I have 4 data values named d1,d2,d3,d4.
And each of these in order are 0,1,0,0 or off,on,off,off.
What I don't want is the line going from d1,0 to d2,1 at an angle. I would like it to stay 0 until the change at d1, then go vertical to 1 and so on.

Any help to guide me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [`stepPlot` option](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#stepPlot):

```js
g = new Dygraph(
  document.getElementById("graph"),
  "t,d1,d2,d3\n" +
  "1,0,0,0\n" +
  "2,1,0,0\n" +
  "3,0,1,0\n" +
  "4,0,0,1\n" +
  "5,1,0,1\n" +
  "6,0,1,0\n" +
  "7,1,1,1\n" +
  "8,0,0,0\n",
  {
    legend: 'always',
    title: 'On/Off Chart',
    valueRange: [0, 1.5],
    stepPlot: true  // <----
  });
```

```css
#graph {
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://dygraphs.com/dygraph-dev.js"></script>

<div id="graph"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks danvk, that works mostly as expected. I ended up writing a php function that populated the data with the appropriate 1's and 0's which worked well. The step graph looks slightly different with no vertical graph lines but it is quite acceptable. Where can I find a list of commands like this?

Comment: Thanks danvk for pointing that out, I have spent quite a bit of time on that page before, but somehow managed not to see that option.